# Can you use JavaScript for changing a existing Python variable?

Tags: javascript, python

I have some code in Python that makes a website. There is some JavaScript I need. Using JavaScript, I want to change a Python variable.

In the `a` tags under the `nav`, I want to use JavaScript to change the variable `page`. Please use the `onclick` parameter and a `script` tag.

I have tried searching it up, but none matched my needs. Here is the basic outline of my code. It's not the best way, but I find it useful.

```
from socket import *


def create_server():
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        server_socket.bind(('localhost', 9000))
        server_socket.listen(5)

        page = 'home'

        while True:
            (client_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()

            rd = client_socket.recv(5000).decode()
            pieces = rd.split('\n')

            if len(pieces) > 0:
                print(pieces[0])

            data = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
        data += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
        data += '''<html>
                        <head>
                            <style>
                                body {
                                    font-family: "Avenir Next";
                                }
                                
                                a {
                                    text-decoration: none;
                                }
                                
                                nav ul {
                                    list-style-type: none;
                                    margin: 0;
                                    padding: 0;
                                    overflow: hidden;
                                    background-color: #333;
                                    position: sticky;
                                    top: 0;
                                    border-radius: 7px;
                                }
                                
                                nav ul li {
                                    float: left;
                                }
                                
                                nav ul li a {
                                    display: block;
                                    color: white;
                                    text-align: center;
                                    padding: 14px 16px;
                                    text-decoration: none;
                                }
                                
                                nav ul li a:hover {
                                    background-color: #111;
                                }
                                
                                .active {
                                    background-color: #4CAF50;
                                }
                            </style>
                '''

        data += f'''
                            <title>{page.title()} | MySite</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a {'class="active"' if page == 'home' else ''} href="#" onclick="SOMETHING">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a {'class="active"' if page == 'about' else ''} href="#" onclick="SOMETHING">About MySite<a></li>
                                    <li style="float:right"><a {'class="active"' if page == 'login' else ''} href="#" onclick="return">Login</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                            <center>
                                <h1>MySite</h1>
                                <h2>Nice Subheading<p>
                            </center>
                        </body>
                    </html>\r\n\r\n'''
            client_socket.sendall(data.encode())
            client_socket.shutdown(SHUT_WR)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nShutting Down...\n')
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f'\n\nError:\n{exc}')

    server_socket.close()


print('Access http://localhost:9000\n\nRequests:')
create_server()
```

Comment: So can you explain what your code actually does, which variable you want changed, and where you're stuck?

Comment: Sorry, but there is too much context to explain to answer your question here. Python runs in one environment (acting as a server), Javascript in another (in your browser, a client). To make JavaScript affect the Python code you need to have some kind of messaging going on back from the client to the server. That means you need to either make a request to the server that the server understands (usually additional HTTP requests, via DOM calls to open links, submit forms, or by using AJAX) or open additional connections (e.g. a websocket).

Comment: What exactly applies requires details, and you didn't give us much.

Comment: I changed it so it may be easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. The only way is having a endpoint where you send a http request to an api endpoint or something similar

Comment: I made it less broad, is it possible to re-open the question?